# How to do Join in Linq query on column A or column B

Tags: c#, sql, .net, linq

I want to perform a join on a any of the two columns that has the given value

How to convert for example the following SQL query to it's equivalent in Linq (method syntax):

```
select f.Id fId, b.Id bId from Foo f
inner join Bar b on f.FooVal = b.BarValCol1 or f.FooVal = b.BarValCol2
```

I started doing the following :

```
Context.Foos
.Join(Context.Bars, f => f.FooVal, b => b.BarValCol1 [OR?] b.BarValCol2, (f, b) => new { f, b })
.Select(bf => new { fId = bf.f.Id, bId = bf.b.Id })
```

(in this example the two columns contain integer values)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`INNER JOIN` is a more readable syntax, but it can be translated, in pure SQL, into cartesian product of the tables filtered with a `WHERE` clause.

So we can simply use a `WHERE` clause and build the linq from that:

```
from x in Foo
from y in Bar
    .Where(y => y.field1 == x.field1 || y.field2 == x.field2)
```

Ps: `INNER JOIN` and `WHERE` are not evaluated at the same time in SQL so they are not equivalent. `ON` condition filter the `INNER JOIN` then the `WHERE` is apply. But even they will have the same result but not the same execution plan depending on the Database of course.

Comment: @yusufhayırsever, I apologise. I saw by your instant removing that I did not communicate properly. This is not harassment. I do think that the answer is valid. Not it it's current form tho. And attribution is something important.

Comment: It was valid critic i think one can learn from. Imagine a long ass string. Passing it to char array is one memory copy, one iteration. reversing it is an other iteration and memory copy. then converting it to string is yet an other iteration and memory copy. When inverting the iteration in the foor loop remove that cost 3 times. And other exemple the first if, invert the value of string , when you can recursivly call the same method with the parameter in the right order, and don't leave 3 copy of the long string in memory.

Comment: @yusufhayırsever, I wish you a good day. I hope you won't hold any gurdge about my poor communication skill. I once more apologise for it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use your LINQ twice:

```
Context.Foos
  .Join(Context.Bars, f => f.FooVal, b => b.BarValCol1, (f, b) => new { f, b })
  .Select(bf => new { fId = bf.f.Id, bId = bf.b.Id }).ToList().AddRange(
  Context.Foos
    .Join(Context.Bars, f => f.FooVal, b => b.BarValCol2, (f, b) => new { f, b })
    .Select(bf => new { fId = bf.f.Id, bId = bf.b.Id })
  ).Distinct();
```

Comment: what if row meet both conditions? you will have duplicates

Comment: i mean if `FooVal` equal to  `BarValCol1` AND `BarValCol2`. In OP version they expect this row to be returned only once. You will have it twice in resulting list